# is it possible to create multiple schema with in single datable

Tags: mysql

I need to know about whether is it possible to create multiple schema with in single datable please suggest me for example i need to create two different table in two different schema within single database.

Comment: schema is a "database". 2 schemas means 2 databases, and yes they can be in 1 "database", where database means mysql instance.

Comment: In your query you used 3 words (objects) table, schema, database...table and database is clear please clear what is schema in your query. So that some one can help you.

Answer (score 0):

DATABASES CANNOT be nested. i.e., one database can not contain another.

If you want to refer to a table in different Database then refers with `other_db_name`.`table_name`

> i need to create two different table in two different schema within
>   single database.

And as much as i know `SCHEMA` is same as `DATABASE`